# Descriptor class with advanced (inspect/metaclass) functionality

Tags: python, object-oriented, meta-programming

Having answered [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290878/110531) over on Programmers.SE, I found myself wondering how much effort it would be to write a descriptor that can automatically figure out what the 'destination' attribute would be, e.g.:

```
class Demo(object):

    foo = Something()
```

would redirect access to the `foo` attribute to `_foo` by default. To do this, I looked into `inspect` to determine the name to which the descriptor is being assigned (see `BaseDescriptor._get_name`).

Given that the `BaseDescriptor` on its own is pretty pointless, I also created a metaclass to enforce that at least one of the descriptor protocol methods is implemented in any sub-classes of it (which required borrowing part of `six` to keep it 2.x-and-3.x-compliant).

I've included some basic doctests and a demo sub-class to enforce attribute types; what do you think? Using `inspect` makes the auto-naming somewhat fragile (it will probably only work with CPython, and assumes that the descriptor is assigned on a single line), but what else haven't I thought of?

```
from inspect import currentframe, getouterframes

def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):
    """Create a base class with a metaclass.

    Source:
      https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

    License:
      Copyright (c) 2010-2015 Benjamin Peterson
      Released under http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

    """
    class metaclass(meta):
        def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
            return meta(name, bases, d)
    return type.__new__(metaclass, 'temporary_class', (), {})


class EnforceDescriptor(type):
    """Ensures that at least one descriptor method is implemented.

    Notes:
      Requires at least one of the three descriptor protocol methods
      (__get__, __set__ and __delete__) to be implemented.

    Attributes:
      REQUIRED (tuple): The names of the required methods.

    Raises:
      TypeError: If none of the three REQUIRED methods are implemented.

    Example:

        >>> class TestClass(with_metaclass(EnforceDescriptor)):
        ...     pass
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          ...
        TypeError: 'TestClass' must implement at least one descriptor method

    """

    REQUIRED = ('__get__', '__set__', '__delete__')

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if all(attrs.get(name) is None for name in cls.REQUIRED):
            msg = '{!r} must implement at least one descriptor method'
            raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
        return super(EnforceDescriptor, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class BaseDescriptor(with_metaclass(EnforceDescriptor)):
    """Descriptor base class, providing basic set, get and del methods.

    Notes:
      Attempts to determine an appropriate name for the destination
      attribute if one is not explicitly supplied, defaulting to the
      name to which the descriptor is assigned with a leading
      underscore. This uses inspect and is somewhat fragile.

    Arguments:
      name (str, optional): The internal 'destination' attribute to
        redirect access to. Defaults to None.

    Raises:
      ValueError: If the name isn't explicitly supplied and can't be
        determined by inspection.

    Example:

        >>> class TestClass(object):
        ...     foo = BaseDescriptor()


        >>> inst = TestClass()
        >>> inst.foo = 'bar'
        >>> inst._foo
        'bar'
        >>> inst.foo
        'bar'
        >>> del inst.foo
        >>> inst.foo
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          ...
        AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute '_foo'

    """

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = self._get_name() if name is None else name

    def _get_name(self):
        """Attempt to determine an appropriate name by inspection."""
        try:
            code = next(frame for frame in getouterframes(currentframe())
                        if frame[3] not in ('_get_name', '__init__'))[4]
            name = '_{}'.format(code[0].split('=')[0].strip())
        except (IndexError, OSError, TypeError):
            raise ValueError('name could not be determined by inspection '
                             'so must be supplied')
        return name

    def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        setattr(obj, self.name, val)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        delattr(obj, self.name)


class TypedAttribute(BaseDescriptor):
    """Descriptor to limit attribute values to a specified type.

    Arguments:
      type_ (type or tuple, optional): Valid type of the attribute, or
      a tuple of valid types. Defaults to object.

    Example:

        >>> class TestClass(object):
        ...     num = TypedAttribute(type_=(int, float))


        >>> inst = TestClass()
        >>> inst.num = 50
        >>> inst.num
        50
        >>> inst.num = 'bar'
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          ...
        TypeError: value must be one of (int, float)
        >>> inst.num
        50

    """

    def __init__(self, name=None, type_=object):
        super(TypedAttribute, self).__init__(name)
        self.type_ = type_

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.type_):
            if isinstance(self.type_, tuple):
                types = ', '.join(typ.__name__ for typ in self.type_)
                msg = 'value must be one of ({})'.format(types)
            else:
                msg = 'value must be {}'.format(self.type_.__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)
        super(TypedAttribute, self).__set__(obj, val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll talk about the little stuff first

#### Name shadowing

Personal preference, I'm not a huge fan of using the same variable name in your generator expression as you did in the parameters to `__new__` in your `EnforceDescriptor` metaclass.  I'd prefer something like

```
if all(attrs.get(func_name) is None for func_name in cls.REQUIRED):
```

#### Code comments

Your method of getting the name is a little confusing - I had to read it about three times and check the `inspect` docs to fully understand how it works (of course, anything involving inspection is usually a little tricky).  I, and presumably anyone who wanted to touch this in the future, would appreciate some comments as to why things happen why they do.  For example,

```
code = next(frame for frame in getouterframes(currentframe())
            if frame[3] not in ('_get_name', '__init__'))[4]
```

could use a comment indicating that you're finding the first frame that wasn't this function or the `__init__` function of the descriptor.  Then maybe an explanation about why the 4th and 5th items in that frame are important.

#### Name unused variables with `_`

I'd rather see

```
def __get__(self, obj, _):
    return getattr(obj, self.name)
```

than

```
def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
    return getattr(obj, self.name)
```

My IDE highlights `typ=None` so I know it's not used, and this is a simple function, but using `_` makes it even easier to see that parameter can be ignored.

---

Now here's the more interesting things, imo.

### Better way of naming the descriptor's attribute

Like you said, using inspect is pretty fragile.  It'll likely fail on non-CPython implementations, and it's pretty hard to read.  I think a better way to do this is with a metaclass that enforces naming of all descriptors, like so.

```
class EnforceNamedDescriptors(type):
    """Ensures that every instance of a BaseDescriptor has a name for
    its attribute.
    """

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for attr_name, attr_value in attrs.items():
            if (isinstance(attr_value, BaseDescriptor) and
                    not hasattr(attr_value, "name")):
                attr_value.name = "_{}".format(attr_name)
        return super(EnforceNamedDescriptors, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

then just make all classes that are going to use this functionality like so

```
class TestClass(with_metaclass(EnforceNamedDescriptors):
    ...
```

or even make a mixin class like that so you don't have to do that every time.  You could still include the `_get_name` function as a fallback, in case you don't want this auto-naming to work every time.  Then you'd probably change `BaseDescriptor` to look sort of like

```
def __init__(self, name=None):
    if name is not None:
        self.name = name
    # Otherwise fall back to _get_name and EnforceNamedDescriptors

def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
    if not hasattr(self, 'name'):
        self.name = self._get_name()
    return getattr(obj, self.name)
```

One possible issue with this is if, for some ungodly reason, someone wanted to do

```
class TestClass(with_metaclass(EnforceNamedDescriptors)):
    __mangled = TypedAttribute(type=(int, float))
```

you might run into some weird issues... but I figure if someone is doing this much weirdness they probably deserve whatever is coming to them.

### Other ways of avoiding using inspection

I think that you might also be able to avoid using inspection AND metaclasses if you don't mind a little overhead on the first time access of the attribute's value.  If you pull the code from the meta class into the `__get__` of `BaseDescriptor` you could do something like

```
def __get__(self, obj, typ=None):
    if not hasattr(self, 'name'):
        for name, value in obj.__dict__.items():
            if (isinstance(value, BaseDescriptor) and not
                    hasattr(value, 'name')):
                value.name = "_{}".format(name)
    return getattr(obj, self.name)
```

which would add names to every descriptor the first time you access one.  This might get a little unwieldy if there were a ton of these in a given class, but I suspect that this would be okay in most use cases.